# ActiveMq Kaha concurrentStoreAndDispatchQueues implications when is true?

Tags: activemq-classic

I would like to know if there is any implication when using concurrentStoreAndDispatchQueues = true with persistent messages and needed guaranty order.

We are using Kaha, with persistent messages and we need guaranty order, we re using also JMSXGroupID.

Is there any implication setting this to true, is it possible lost of messages?

Any help or clarification about the property concurrentStoreAndDispatchTopics will be helpful.

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

I think `concurrentStoreAndDispatchQueues` option improves the performance of message consumption from ActiveMQ queues. But it is less reliable than synchronous store and dispatch.

In case of concurrent store and dispatch broker does not wait for acknowledgments from consumer or message storage. It dispatches the message to consumers and to message storage thread in parallel and immediately sends back the acknowledgment to message producers.

So there is chance of messages being lost in case of message storage disk issues.

Please refer the documentation from Fuse ESB which explains the similar concept -
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB/4.4.1/html/ActiveMQ_Tuning_Guide/files/PersTuning-SerialToDisk.html